# Labelling individual data points gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Just trying to get used to gnuplot. I searched a few pages on this site looking for the answer, read the documentation (4.6), and still haven't found the answer. say I have a data file like this:

```
0.0 0
1.0 25
2.0 55
3.0 110
4.0 456
5.0 554
6.0 345
```

and I want to label all the data points on the plot. How do I do this? I tried this suggestion `plot 'exp.dat' u 1:2 w labels point offset character 0,character 1 tc rgb "blue"` but it didn't work. It gave me a `Not enough columns for this style` response. I'm sure it's something I'm doing but I'm not sure what. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing strings for labels. You can do

```
flabel(y)=sprintf("y=%.2f", y)
plot '-' u 1:2:(flabel($2)) w labels point offset character 0,character 1 tc rgb "blue"
0.0 0
1.0 25
2.0 55
3.0 110
4.0 456
5.0 554
6.0 345
```

[image]

Comment: Here is an interesting variation:  Simply labeling the last label of a data-logging system that used `reread ` to keep it live.  Might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152083/is-there-a-way-to-put-a-label-for-the-last-entry-in-gnuplot/28152491#28152491

Comment: Thanks. You can use `notitle` to hide the legend on the top left. For example, i am using something like this `'' using 7:($18/1000):(sprintf("%.2f", $14/$18)) with labels notitle offset character 0,character 1`.