# gnuplot: how to label points in multiplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to label points on the plot using 'with labels' command but I get 'not enough columns for this style' error. My datafile looks like this:

```
method ∆G

A    0
B    15.01
C   -1.4
D    12.2
E   -3.9

method ∆H

A    0
B    8.4
C   -2.58
D    3.6
E   -2.12

method ∆SCF

A    0
B    11.66
C   -0.96
D    6.28
E   -1.3
```

I use this command to create a plot:

```
plot 'file.dat' using 2:xticlabel(1) index 0 pointtype 18 wth labels,''using 2 index 1 pointtype 18 with labels,''using 2 index 2 pointtype 18 with labels
```

I know that 'with labels' command requires 3 arguments, so the problem is probably lack of the third argument, but I've checked many combination and there was always some error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `labels` plotting style has nothing to do with `xticlabels`. The latter reads xticlabels from the data file, whereas the `labels` plotting style places a label at the given coordinates. So you're probably missing two columns. Another remark: `index` doesn't work for the file as you show it. For this you must separate two data blocks by *two* blank lines.

Comment: No, you need a third item in the colons.  First is x, 2nd is y, and 3rd is label.  Here it how to label every single point:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520684/labelling-individual-data-points-gnuplot?rq=1  and here is how to label the very last (most recent) data point on a live data logging system that uses `reread` to keep the plot live:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152083/is-there-a-way-to-put-a-label-for-the-last-entry-in-gnuplot/28152491#28152491

Answer (score 0):

For your "missing" 3rd column you can use the pseudocolumn 0 (check `help pseudocolumns`).

If you want to address blocks via `index` you need to have two empty lines as separator. If you change your datafile format a bit it will make your script simpler.

The labels will have an offset depending on the sign. You can achieve this with the ternary operator, e.g. `($2<0?-1:1)`, (check `help ternary`). You could add another fixed offset via `offset` (check `help label`).

**Data:** `SO24044166.dat`

```
method ∆G
A    0
B    15.01
C   -1.4
D    12.2
E   -3.9


method ∆H
A    0
B    8.4
C   -2.58
D    3.6
E   -2.12


method ∆SCF
A    0
B    11.66
C   -0.96
D    6.28
E   -1.3
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot 4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### use of pseudocolumn as x-value
reset

FILE = "SO24044166.dat"

set key title "methods" noautotitle
set style fill solid 0.3
set grid y
set yrange[-6:18]

set boxwidth 0.23
plot for [i=0:2] FILE u ($0+i/3.5):2 index i w boxes ti columnhead, \
     for [i=0:2] ''   u ($0+i/3.5):($2+($2<0?-1:1)):2 index i every ::1 w labels offset 0,0 notitle, \
                 ''   u ($0+1/3.5):(NaN):xtic(1) index 0 every ::1
### end of script
```

**Result:** (created with gnuplot 4.6.0)

[image]