# Is there a way to put a label for the last entry in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to use gnuplot for real time plotting (Data gets appended to file which I use for plotting and I use replot for real time plotting). I also want to put a label for the latest entry which is plotted. So as to get a idea what is the latest value. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on a unixoid system, you can use `tail` to extract the last line from the file and plot it separately in whatever way you desire. To give a simple example:

```
plot\
"data.dat" w l,\
"< tail -n 1 data.dat" u 1:2:2 w labels notitle
```

This will plot the whole of `data.dat` with lines and the last point with labels, with the label depicting the value.

Comment: Hey, This worked fine. Except with one little change. If we copy the above script then '< tail -n 1 data.dat' etc also came in the label. So to avoid this add notitle after labels in the last line.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want, but I do not understand the 1:2:2 - it would make sense to me if it were the columns I am plotting but if that were true then there would only be two of them.  Can you explain that part, please?  I am working on input from a data logger.  My plot command is `"today.dat" using 2:($3) skip 2 with lines lc rgb 'red' t "Battery"` and I need a text label showing the most recent reading.

Comment: OK, YEAH!   I figured out that the third number is where the label comes from.  I found it here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520684/labelling-individual-data-points-gnuplot

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use the Linux command `tail`, you can simply do it with *gnuplot-only*, hence platform-independently.
The principle: while plotting the data, you assign the values of column 1 and 2 to variables `x0` and `y0`, respectively.
After the first plot command, `x0` and `y0` will contain the last values.
With this, you don't have to load the file a second time for extracting the last values.

For the label plotting, use these values and print the label with a `sprintf()` expression (check `help sprintf`).
The construct `'+' u ... every ::0::0` is just one way of [many ways to plot a single data point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19452516/7295599).

**Data:** `SO28152083.dat`

```
 1   5.1
 2   2.2
 3   3.3
 4   1.4
 5   4.5
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot 4.4.0, March 2010 or even with earlier versions)

```
### plot last value as label
reset

FILE = "SO28152083.dat"

set key noautotitle
set offsets 0.5,0.5,1,1

plot FILE u (x0=$1):(y0=$2) w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red" ti "data", \
      '+' u (x0):(y0):(sprintf("%g",y0)) every ::0::0 w labels offset 0,1
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]